# I am unable to store string into an array, which i then want to use for comparison

Tags: c++, arrays, string

I am unable to store the string into an array, when I output `b[c]` nothing appears whatsoever, how can I store it into an array?

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    string b[80000];
    int c=0;
    string s;
    ifstream file(argv[1]);

    while(file >> s) {
        b[c]=s;
        c++;
        cout<<b[c];
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In `C` you don't have inbuild `string` datatype (you need to done by `char[N]`), and why too long buffer. I think you need [tag:c++] **tag**

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan I've changed the tag from C to C++.

Comment: what happens if there are more than 8000 strings in the given file?

Answer (score 3):

You're printing empty strings. Just move `cout << b[c];` before `c++;`

I'd suggest use `std::vector`, it will avoid unnecessary temporary variables and magic constants:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
    std::ifstream fin(argv[1]);

    std::vector<std::string> v
    {
        std::istream_iterator<std::string>(fin),
        std::istream_iterator<std::string>()
    };

    for(const auto& elem: v)
        std::cout << elem << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Don't forget also handle cases when file name isn't passed, or file doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

This may work

```
while(file >> s) {
            b[c]=s;
            cout<<b[c];
            c++;

        }
```

Comment: ahaa what is `[c]` ?? and why ?

Comment: ok indent you code, also it need an explanation. What was the problem how you resolved.

Comment: It's basically @soon answer: "Just move cout << b[c]; before c++;".